# MySQL connection in Nestjs without ORM

Tags: mysql, nestjs

I'm working with Nestjs and MySQL (just MySQL, not with any ORM) and I need to create a file that contains the following information. I am new to Nestjs and TypeScript and I really don't know how to do it like with JS and Express.

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const database = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "user",
  password: "password",
  database: "database"
});

const data = `
CREATE DATABASE employees;

USE employees;

CREATE TABLE users (
  username varchar() NOT NULL,
  email varchar() NOT NULL,
  password varchar() NOT NULL,
  createdAt datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (email)
);
`;

database.connect() => {
  database.query(data, () => {
    console.log("CREATED SUCCESSFULLY");
  });
});

module.exports = database;
```